# SVG viewBox attribute places shape outside artboard in Illustrator

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator, inkscape

I am writing an `SVG` file that fits the shapes inside an artboard, by using the [viewBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) attribute. In Inkscape, the shapes are inside the artboard. But in Adobe Illustrator, the shape is placed above the artboard (vertically). How should I make the art fit for any software the SVG is going to be opened with?

The shape below forms the `Z` character. The svg code :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" 
 width="22.640625" height="28.640625" viewBox="0.796875 -28.640625 22.640625 28.640625" >
<path d=" M 0.796875, 0.0 L 0.796875, -3.515625 L 15.46875, -21.859375 Q 17.03125, -23.8125 18.4375, -25.25
 L 2.46875, -25.25 L 2.46875, -28.640625 L 22.96875, -28.640625 L 22.96875, -25.25 L 6.890625, -5.390625
 L 5.15625, -3.375 L 23.4375, -3.375 L 23.4375, 0.0 L 0.796875, 0.0 Z"/>
</svg>
```

And the appearance in Illustrator:

[image: letter Z on top of the artboard in Illustrator]

Comment: It would help if you posted the SVG code, so we can see how you're using the `viewBox` attribute. It would also help to see a screen shot of your SVG in Illustrator.

Comment: i want to display the two different shapes Inkscpe and Adobe Illustrator how is the first one is fitting the art-board,but not the secode software, but i don't have enough reputation

Comment: OK, I see the problem now. But I don't know how to fix it; sorry. I did edit the question to make it clearer what the problem is. Hopefully someone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe illustrator reads in viewbox info when opening an svg. It just uses the width and height and draws the artboad from 0,0. If your paths have any negative values or values larger than the respective width or height, they will appear off of the dartboard. If you make your files in illustrator, a new document will export its artboard coordinates as viewbox coordinates starting at 0,0 and should open correctly in other programs. If you are going to create images in other software to open in illustrator, you need to set your document up so that the viewbox starts at 0,0 and the path all have positive coordinates. That process will likely be different in various vector apps.